# Reading multiple files in python

Tags: python, filereader

I have a dataset of more than 300k files which I need to read and append to dictionary.

```
corpus_path = "data"
article_paths = [os.path.join(corpus_path,p) for p in os.listdir(corpus_path)]

doc = []
for path in article_paths:
    dp = pd.read_table(path, header=None, encoding='utf-8', quoting=3, error_bad_lines=False)
    doc.append(dp)
```

Is there a faster way to do this, as the current method takes more than an hour.

Comment: If you have ssd then you can try threads. Otherwise probably no.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)** module.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def readFile(path):
    return pd.read_table(path, header=None, encoding='utf-8', quoting=3, error_bad_lines=False)


result = list(Pool(processes=nprocs).imap(readFile, article_paths))  #nprocs = Number of processors
```